# How is this algorithm O(n)?

Tags: time-complexity

Working through the recurrences, you can derive that during each call to this function, the time complexity will be: `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1)`

And the height of the recurrence tree would be `log2(n)`, where is the total number of calls (i.e. nodes in the tree).

It was said by the instructor that this function has a time complexity of O(n), but I simply cannot see why.

[image]

Further, when you substitute O(n) into the time complexity equation there are strange results. For example,

T(n) <= cn

T(n/2) <= (cn)/2

Back into the original equation:

T(n) <= cn + 1

Where this is obviously not true because `cn + 1 !< cn`

Comment: maybe you could ask this at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was not aware that existed, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instructor is correct. This is an application of the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Application_to_common_algorithms).

You can't substitute O(n) like you did in the time complexity equation, a correct substitution would be a polynomial form like an + b, since O(n) only shows the highest significant degree (there can be constants of lower degree).

To expand on the answer, you correctly recognize an time complexity equation of the form 
`T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)`, with a = 2, b = 2 and f(n) asympt. equals O(1).
With this type of equations, you have three cases that depends on the compared value of log_b(a) (cost of recursion) and of f(n) (cost of solving the basic problem of length n):
1° f(n) is much longer than the recursion itself (log_b(a) < f(n)), for instance a = 2, b = 2 and f(n) asympt. equals O(n^16). Then the recursion is of negligible complexity and the total time complexity can be assimilated to the complexity of f(n):

```
T(n) = f(n)
```

2° The recursion is longer than f(n) (log_b(a) > f(n)), which is the case here Then the complexity is O(log_b(a)), in your example O(log_2(2)), ie O(n).

3° The critical case where f(n) == log_b(a), ie there exists k >= 0 such that f(n) = O(n^{log_b(a)} log^k (n)), then the complexity is:

```
T(n) = O(n^{log_b(a)} log^k+1 (a)}
```

This is the ugly case in my opinion.